# React.js Display Data Using onClick

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**Change This From To Display Data When we click on submit**
*Currently it is displaying on when we write in input fields*

I Tried by using another another useState() and passing the values in it   then created another function and passed it on onClick()  but it does't work screen went blank after that

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
// Imports

const Register = () => {
    const [
        register,
        registerForm,
    ] = useState({
        Email: '',
        Username: '',
        Password: '',
        ConfirmPassword: '',
    });
    const changed = (e) => {
        const { name, value } = e.target;
        registerForm((pval) => {
            return {
                ...pval,
                [name]: value,
            };
        });
    };
    return (
        <>
            <div className="inside_form">
                <table>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <div>
                                    <img alt="" src="" />
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <div>
                                    <h2>Sign up for your Account</h2>
                                    <p>
                                        This is Photoshop's of Lorem Ipsum velit
                                        auctor aliquet.
                                    </p>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <div>
                                    <p>{register.Email}</p>
                                    <label>EMAIL</label>
                                    <br />
                                    <input
                                        type="email"
                                        onChange={changed}
                                        name="Email"
                                        value={register.Email}
                                    />
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <div>
                                    <p>{register.Username}</p>
                                    <label>USERNAME</label>
                                    <br />
                                    <input
                                        type="text"
                                        onChange={changed}
                                        name="Username"
                                        value={register.Username}
                                    />
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <div>
                                    <p>{register.Password}</p>
                                    <label>PASSSWORD</label>
                                    <br />
                                    <input
                                        type="password"
                                        onChange={changed}
                                        name="Password"
                                        value={register.Password}
                                    />
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <div>
                                    <p>{register.ConfirmPassword}</p>
                                    <label>CONFIRM PASSWORD</label>
                                    <br />
                                    <input
                                        type="password"
                                        onChange={changed}
                                        name="ConfirmPassword"
                                        value={register.ConfirmPassword}
                                    />
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <div>
                                    <input type="submit" />
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </>
    );
};
export default Register;
```

Comment: Where are you rendering the state values that you want to "wait" to display until the submit button is clicked?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your question.

Comment: Yep its Works Now My Mistake Was i wasn't adding {}  inside the new setstate()   ```const [registerReplica, setRegisterReplica] = useState({});```   I was writing like this ```const [registerReplica, setRegisterReplica] = useState();```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a **replica** of `register` while submitting. And then use **replica state variable** to display those values. Or another solution is to have a flag and then use that flag to show values.

**Stackblitz:** [You can see full solution here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-sghkai)

**Example using replica:**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
// Imports

const Register = () => {
  const [register, registerForm] = useState({
    Email: "",
    Username: "",
    Password: "",
    ConfirmPassword: ""
  });
  const [registerReplica, setRegisterReplica] = useState({});
  const changed = e => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    registerForm(pval => {
      return {
        ...pval,
        [name]: value
      };
    });
  };

  const submit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setRegisterReplica(register);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div className="inside_form">
        <table>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <div>
                  <img alt="" src="" />
                </div>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <div>
                  <h2>Sign up for your Account</h2>
                  <p>
                    This is Photoshop's of Lorem Ipsum velit auctor aliquet.
                  </p>
                </div>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <div>
                  <p>{registerReplica.Email}</p>
                  <label>EMAIL</label>
                  <br />
                  <input
                    type="email"
                    onChange={changed}
                    name="Email"
                    value={register.Email}
                  />
                </div>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <div>
                  <p>{registerReplica.Username}</p>
                  <label>USERNAME</label>
                  <br />
                  <input
                    type="text"
                    onChange={changed}
                    name="Username"
                    value={register.Username}
                  />
                </div>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <div>
                  <p>{registerReplica.Password}</p>
                  <label>PASSSWORD</label>
                  <br />
                  <input
                    type="password"
                    onChange={changed}
                    name="Password"
                    value={register.Password}
                  />
                </div>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <div>
                  <p>{registerReplica.ConfirmPassword}</p>
                  <label>CONFIRM PASSWORD</label>
                  <br />
                  <input
                    type="password"
                    onChange={changed}
                    name="ConfirmPassword"
                    value={register.ConfirmPassword}
                  />
                </div>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <div>
                  <input onClick={submit} type="submit" />
                </div>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};
export default Register;
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to solve your problem. One of them is to have a separate state which change on click of submit. Use the state to display your register values.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
// Imports

const Register = () => {
    const [showValues, setShowValues] = useState(false);
    const [
        register,
        registerForm,
    ] = useState({
        Email: '',
        Username: '',
        Password: '',
        ConfirmPassword: '',
    });
    const changed = (e) => {
        const { name, value } = e.target;
        registerForm((pval) => {
            return {
                ...pval,
                [name]: value,
            };
        });
    };
    return (
        <>
            <div className="inside_form">
                <table>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <div>
                                    <img alt="" src="" />
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <div>
                                    <h2>Sign up for your Account</h2>
                                    <p>
                                        This is Photoshop's of Lorem Ipsum velit
                                        auctor aliquet.
                                    </p>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <div>
                                    <p>{showValues && register.Email}</p>
                                    <label>EMAIL</label>
                                    <br />
                                    <input
                                        type="email"
                                        onChange={changed}
                                        name="Email"
                                        value={register.Email}
                                    />
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <div>
                                    <p>{showValues && register.Username}</p>
                                    <label>USERNAME</label>
                                    <br />
                                    <input
                                        type="text"
                                        onChange={changed}
                                        name="Username"
                                        value={register.Username}
                                    />
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <div>
                                    <p>{showValues && register.Password}</p>
                                    <label>PASSSWORD</label>
                                    <br />
                                    <input
                                        type="password"
                                        onChange={changed}
                                        name="Password"
                                        value={register.Password}
                                    />
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <div>
                                    <p>{showValues && register.ConfirmPassword}</p>
                                    <label>CONFIRM PASSWORD</label>
                                    <br />
                                    <input
                                        type="password"
                                        onChange={changed}
                                        name="ConfirmPassword"
                                        value={register.ConfirmPassword}
                                    />
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <div>
                                    <input type="submit" onClick={() => setShowValues(true)} />
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </>
    );
};
export default Register;
```